# How to scale a reactjs component into the browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scale

How to I scale a react component already created into the browser that already has a height and width predefined???

```
componentDidMount(x,y,z){
 this.setState({height:window.innerHeight+'px'});
}
```

Not sure if this is the right way to go, I am not sure if I have to get th viewport size first and then later try to scale the  on the browser later. How to can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the styles directly to the DOM element. For example:

```
render() {
    return <div style={{ height: window.innerHeight }} />;
}
```

If you need to calculate the style after initial render, perhaps after some user interaction, you could calculate and store the styles in state:

```
// ... calculate and set state logic somewhere
// eg: someFunction() { this.setState({ height: window.innerHeight }); }
render() {
    let styles = {};
    if (this.state.height) {
        styles.height = this.state.height;
    }

    return <div style={styles} />;
}
```